# how to add data to list then detect and delete it

Tags: flutter

how can i add data to List<> imgList if i pick image 2nd time then delete 1st data i add i try to use index to check is this can do ?

```
  List<File?> files = [];
  File? file;
  List<ImageConfig> imgList = [];

Future<void> processImagePicker(ImageSource imageSource, int index) async {
    try {
      var result = await ImagePicker()
          .pickImage(source: imageSource, maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 700);

      setState(() {
        file = File(result!.path);
        files[index] = file;
        imgList.add(ImageConfig(
            source: "picture", path: result.path, index: index.toString()));
      });

      for (var item in imgList) {
        print('object ===> ${item.index}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

class ImageCongfig is

```
class ImageConfig {
  String? source;
  String? path;
  String? index;
  ImageConfig({this.source, this.path, this.index});
}
```

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find item by using firstWhere method.
And remove that item from itemList.

```
void main() {
  List<ImageConfig> datas = [
     ImageConfig(source: '1', path: '1-2', index: '1-3'),
     ImageConfig(source: '2', path: '2-2', index: '2-3'),
     ImageConfig(source: '3', path: '3-2', index: '1-3'),
  ];
  
  print(datas);
  var foundItem = datas.firstWhere((item) => item.index == '1-3');
  print('foundItem: $foundItem');
  datas.remove(foundItem);
  print(datas);
  
}


class ImageConfig {
  String? source;
  String? path;
  String? index;
  ImageConfig({this.source, this.path, this.index});
  
  
  @override
  String toString() => '''ImageConfig { source: $source,
 path: $path,
 index: $index}''';
}
```

[image]

Comment: if only index was repeat how can i solve it my data like List<ImageConfig> datas = [
     ImageConfig(source: '1', path: '1', index: '1'),
     ImageConfig(source: '2', path: '2-2', index: '0'),
     ImageConfig(source: '1', path: '1234', index: '1'),
  ];

Comment: Opps, if that, just use firstWhere.

imgList.firstWhere((item) => item.index == index);

Comment: I changed code to find item by index only